# The method <method> is undefined for the type string

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, methods

Ok, so I have a super class with a getter method below:

```
public String getBorrowerID(){
return borrowerID;
}
```

And then I have a subclass with a new array declared as an instance variable to store userIDs:

```
private String [] resQueue = new String[5];
```

And a borrow method with a variable called 'borrowerID' passed in as a parameter where I have to compare the first ID in the array with the  borrowerID :

```
 if( borrowerID == resQueue[0].getBorrowerID())
 {
     super.borrow(borrowerID);
     resCount--;
```

However, I get an error "The method getBorrowerID() is undefined for the type String" on this line:

```
    if( borrowerID == resQueue[0].getBorrowerID())
```

Any ideas?

Comment: getBorrowerID() is not a method for String. How can you use over string ?

Comment: On a side note: `==` is not the best way to check strings equality.

Comment: What you expect `resQueue[0].getBorrowerID()` do?

Comment: I think David's solution has helped me. And also, yes you guys are right, using "==" was not the best way to go about this. Thanks for the replies. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

`getBorrowerID()` is defined in one of your classes , not in `String`, so you call call it though a `String` reference.

You can call it only through an instance of the class that contains it. For example, if your class that contains `getBorrowerID()` is called `YourClass`, you can call that method this way:

```
YourClass var = new YourClass();
String id = var.getBorrowerID();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
if ( resQueue[0].equals(getBorrowerID()) ) {
    // ...
}
```